# After Retrofit Call User Interface get Hangs in andriod

Tags: android, user-interface, retrofit, retrofit2, android-studio-3.0

After i Submit The Request i recieve the data using Retrofit from the Json Response.But user interface get Hangs after i rotate my app the data which i request is Null.Again i have to give request.Please help me to short out this problem it will be great help.
Here is the Code

***code***

```
public class ApiClient {
    public static final String BASE_URL = " ";  //Duplicate URL
    public static Retrofit retrofit=null;
    public static Retrofit getClient()
    {
        if(retrofit==null)
        {
            retrofit=new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(BASE_URL).
                    addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }
}
```

Fragment Call 
Here i call the retrofit and submit the value i got the output but after that it gets hangs the user-interface.

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        v= inflater.inflate( R.layout.fragstaff_report, container, false );
        recyclerView=(RecyclerView) v.findViewById( R.id.recyclerview_report );
        layoutManager=new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        datepick=(EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.from_date);
        datepick1=(EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.to_date);
        Button btn1=(Button)v.findViewById( R.id.btn_report);
        SharedDataUserEmail = SharedPrefManager.getInstans( getActivity() ).getUserEmail();
        datepick.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Initialize a new date picker dialog fragment
                DialogFragment dFragment = new Fragement2.DatePickerFragment();
                // Show the date picker dialog fragment
                dFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "Date Picker");
                startEndDAte = true;
            }
        });


        datepick1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Initialize a new date picker dialog fragment
                DialogFragment dFragment = new Fragement2.DatePickerFragment();
                // Show the date picker dialog fragment
                dFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "Date Picker");
                startEndDAte = false;
            }
        });
        btn1.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                FromDate = datepick.getText().toString();
                Date date=new Date(FromDate);
                SimpleDateFormat formatter=new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-dd");
                 FromDateLocal = formatter.format(date);


                ToDate = datepick1.getText().toString();
                Date date1=new Date(ToDate);
                SimpleDateFormat formatter1=new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-dd");
                 DateformatTo = formatter1.format(date1);



                final ProgressDialog mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog( getActivity() );
                (getActivity()).getWindow().setFlags( WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE,
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE );
                mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate( true );
                mProgressDialog.setMessage( "Loading..." );
                mProgressDialog.show();


                apiInterface = ApiClient.getClient(httpClient).create( ApiInterface.class );
                Call<List<VirtualFragementModel>> call = apiInterface.getEmployeeReport(FromDateLocal,DateformatTo,SharedDataUserEmail);
                Toast.makeText( getActivity(),"New From Date "+FromDateLocal+" To Date "+ DateformatTo+"Emailid "+SharedDataUserEmail,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                call.enqueue( new Callback<List<VirtualFragementModel>>() {


                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<List<VirtualFragementModel>> call, Response<List<VirtualFragementModel>> response) {
                        if (mProgressDialog.isShowing())
                        {
                            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                        }
                        virtualFragementModels=response.body();
                        employerReportAdapter=new EmployerReportAdapter(virtualFragementModels,getActivity());
                        recyclerView.setAdapter(employerReportAdapter);

                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<List<VirtualFragementModel>> call, Throwable t) {

                        Toast.makeText( getActivity(),"Welcome error Handling Session",Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
                    }
                } );
            }
        } );
        return v;
    }
```

***CODE***

Comment: Does my answer work?

Answer (score 2):

For this you can use `onSaveInstanceState()` and `onRestoreInstanceState()` methods because When you rotate your device, your present activity gets completely destroyed, it goes through `onSaveInstanceState()` `onPause()` `onStop()` `onDestroy()` and a new activity is created completely which goes through `onCreate()` `onStart()` `onRestoreInstanceState()`.

**You can save your variable like this :**

```
 @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState, PersistableBundle outPersistentState) {

        //In your case you can save your response body here
        outState.putString("jack", jack); // Saving the Variable jack
        outState.putStringArrayList("arrayList", arrayList); // Saving the arrayList 
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState, outPersistentState);
    }
```

**Then you can get your variables like this :**

```
@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState, PersistableBundle persistentState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState, persistentState);

    jack = savedInstanceState.getString("jack"); // Restoring jack
    arrayList = savedInstanceState.getStringArrayList("arrayList"); //Restoring arrayList
}
```

Comment: milad salimi thanks for the help.But My problem is after reterive the data,that is i got call from onresponse successful my user interface not woking.when im clicking submit buttton again.Im calling by using fragment